# gpio_name_to_desc in gpiolib.c in Linux kernel should be externalized?

Tags: device-tree, gpio

We have an embedded project, and for our purposes, it seems handy to name all the gpios in the gpio controller device tree stanza using gpio-line-names feature in device tree, mentioned in Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt.

The main flaw in this is that the function gpio_name_to_desc() in source/drivers/gpio/gpiolib.c is not externalized for writing kernel drivers.

There seem to be very few examples of gpio-line-names in the kernel.  For instance, arch/arm/boot/dts/ste-hrefv60plus.dtsi has a string HDTV_INTN, but is not used in kernel space anywhere else.

We have looked at the other feature, [-]gpios (and optionally an index), but would prefer the gpio-line-names feature as it is easier to read, and will probably patch our kernel, as it is trivial to externalize the gpio_name_to_desc() function.

Is this a dead or nearly dead feature?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on our team found this patch:

[Export gpio_name_to_desc() to modular GPIO code](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-renesas-soc/patch/20190911143858.13024-4-geert+renesas@glider.be/)

So we are not the only ones who would like this feature.